# Magento2 : How to Connect Local Database with Magento Site to Update Details

Tags: magento2, database

I wanted to update Price Details of products in Magento Site.

My Products details are maintained in `Oracle Database - Local System`.

`Magento is hosted in remote server`.

How can i connect my Magento with my Local Oracle Database.

Please suggest me ideas. How can i do it.

**Edit:**

Can I create a web service for magento2 (a module) which will take SKU , price, Quantity and update the inventry.

Please let me Know how can i find the magento REST Service.